# How can I make an extra field required in flask-admin?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I know using form_extra_fields can add an extra field in flask-admin. But how can I make it 'required'? Thanks in advance.

```
form_extra_fields = {
    'password2': PasswordField('Password')
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Thanks a lot, Mech. 
Actually I figured out a simpler way:

```
from wtforms import validators
form_extra_fields = {
    'password2': PasswordField('password',[validators.DataRequired()])
}
```

Comment: Good to know for future reference!

Answer (score 3):

You can use WTForms. See example below, pulled from [Flask's documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/wtforms/):

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, TextField, PasswordField, validators

class RegistrationForm(Form):
    username = TextField('Username', [validators.Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = TextField('Email Address', [validators.Length(min=6, max=35)])
    password = PasswordField('New Password', [
        validators.Required(),
        validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')
    ])
    confirm = PasswordField('Repeat Password')
    accept_tos = BooleanField('I accept the TOS', [validators.Required()])
```

See the link for the other snippets (view, template, etc).